# Calculate total effort of scheduled tasks

Tags: php, task, histogram

I'm developing a simple project management application in PHP where users are given tasks and these tasks are displayed as bars on a timeline (Gantt chart). The workload of each task is defined by a number which indicates the "units" of work or effort needed to perform the task.

I got stuck when trying to calculate the total effort and get it displayed as shown in chart B.

[image: Gantt chart]

In other words, if I had the tasks:

```
$task1 = array('startDate' => '01-01-2015', 'endDate' => '10-01-2015', 'effort' => 5);
$task2 = array('startDate' => '04-01-2015', 'endDate' => '12-01-2015', 'effort' => 10);
```

The array I'd need in order to create chart B would be:

```
$total = array(
    0 => array('startDate' => '01-01-2015', 'endDate' => '04-01-2015', 'effort' => 5),
    1 => array('startDate' => '04-01-2015', 'endDate' => '10-01-2015', 'effort' => 15),
    2 => array('startDate' => '10-01-2015', 'endDate' => '12-01-2015', 'effort' => 10)
);
```

How can I process the two tasks to give me $total?

Comment: How is this data collected? Do you query it from a database? XML? Json?

Answer (score 0):

I might have misunderstood your question but if you want the total of effort into your array `$total`, you could do the following :

```
$total = array(
    0 => array('startDate' => '01-01-2015', 'endDate' => '04-01-2015', 'effort' => 5),
    1 => array('startDate' => '04-01-2015', 'endDate' => '10-01-2015', 'effort' => 15),
    2 => array('startDate' => '10-01-2015', 'endDate' => '12-01-2015', 'effort' => 10)
);

$totalEffort = 0;
foreach ($total as $task) {
    $totalEffort += $task['effort'];
}
var_dump($totalEffort);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It is not that simple. $task1 and $task2 are my two tasks, what I want to achieve is the array $total... an array that basically tells me what is the total effort in every timespan. The array $total will help me create a chart like the one on the image (chart B).